# Kinect and USB 3.0

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Recently  I bought dell Xps 15 and it has 2 USB 3.0 and just only one usb 2.0 port.

Has anyone get data from kinect successful using USB 3.0.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10663/kinect-and-usb-3.0/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-20**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/147/kinect-and-usb-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/147/kinect-and-usb-30 - tfoote (Jul 20)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0